# Limits in exponential function

Tags: limits

Can anyboy help me how i can compute this limits, I know that it is zero, but how to calculate it?
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} -xe^{-ax}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it as $\displaystyle \frac{-x}{e^{ax}}$ and use l'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 1):

Standard trick: Use $x=e^{\ln{x}}$.